# MacOS notarization and third-party libraries

Tags: macos, code-signing

We have a C# application that runs using Mono. At runtime, this app loads various native dylib files, most of which are open source (e.g. libusb), but some are provided by third parties. How should we handle codesigning for this before submitting an installer dmg for notarization?

Should we just sign all the executable code, including that provided by third parties?

Comment: yes executable code should be signed